# Rails 4 - will_paginate: go to last page by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have a conversation and messages that belong to a conversation. It would make sense to send users directly to the last page of conversation with the latest messages.

Using `.order('created_at DESC')` on messages would not be intuitive to users, because it would put latest messages on top of the first page, which is not how most conversations/forums threads work.

Now I have something like this:

```
@messages = Message.where(conversation_id: params[:id]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

will_paginate supports a page option, so you could always give it the latest page as an argument. Ex:

`messages.paginate(page: latest_page)`

So you just need to implement the `latest_page` method, counting the number of records and dividing by the number of records per page.

Edit:

Something like this:

```
def latest_page
  messages = Message.where(conversation_id: params[:id])
  messages.count / 15
end
```

Comment: Could you please write the method? I understand your basic thinking, but an example would be very useful.